# Getting Message "Failed to generate sample value: generated sample is too big" when clicked on Test tab of the API on Azure APIM Portal

Tags: azure-api-management, web-api-testing

When we visit azure portal->APIM, and browse an API and then try to use the Test tab where we can test various operations under the API, the sample request is not generated and instead we get Failed to generate sample value: generated sample is too big. This is happening for some APIs. Not sure what is the limit or which limit it is breaking.
This also replicates when tried from Developer Portal.

Browse Azure Portal
Go to API Management Service
Select APIs section
Select an API
Select Test tab
Click on the Operation
Expectation was to see Request body with valid sample request
But we get "Failed to generate sample value: generated sample is too big." in the Request body. This is happening only for selected APIs not for all.

Need to understand what is the limit? I have validated that its not an UI client issue i.e. this message comes from server itself when providing the operation details.

Answer (score 0):

The APIM service has a maximum Sample size limit and it is 200kb, and if the sample is larger than this limit, the APIM service will return this error. "Failed to generate sample value: generated sample is too big" in this case you would need to create sample by your own.